# C# Exchange Powershell specified cast not valid

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server

I'm getting a specified cast error trying to return a integer, example code below:

```
results = pipeline.Invoke();

foreach (PSObject ps in results)
{
int diff = 0;
Int32 exchcount = Convert.ToInt32(ps.Members["itemcount"].Value);
diff = itemcount - exchcount;
}
```

I'm trying to find out what the data type if for itemcount of the Get-Mailboxstatistics but i can't find the information, i assume it's Int, i've tried string but that does not work either. any ideas please let me know!

Thanks
Steve

Answer (score 0):

You can put breakpoin in the foreach cycle and see what type is `ps.Members["itemcount"].Value` (e.g. you can do `ps.Members["itemcount"].Value.GetType()` in the Immidiate window).

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is at the `foreach` loop. The variable `ps` is declared of type `PSObject` while `results` might be something else (an array of object which are not of the correct type). Look at the type of the `results` variable.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think it's the foreach statement, if i use a string type value like 'DisplayName' cmd value it works.. only for a value/int type it seems to fail. i'll try and check the break point to see the value type..

Thanks!
ST